Delegating to groups, tasks that loop
I have created a yaml file with a list of dictionaries like below.
connections:
  - { src: group1, dest: group2, type: tcp, port: [22,23,34] }
  - { src: group2, dest: group3, type: tcp, port: [22,23] } 

I need to curate a task that requires me to connect to a group of hosts from another group of hosts to check an open connection.
I need to loop through each host in dest groups and then loop through each port. I can achieve something when using with_subelements but don't understand how I can incorporate looping through groups now.
Below is theoretically what I need my task to do.
- name: Group1 connection test
  hosts: group1
  gather_facts: no
  become: no
  vars_files:
    - ports.yml
  tasks:
    # In theory what I require
    - name: Group1 connection
      shell: nc -l -p "{{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ connections }}"
        - port
      poll: 0
      async: 60
      delegate_to: "{{ group2 }}"

- name: Group2 connection test
  hosts: group2
  gather_facts: no
  become: no
  vars_files:
    - ports.yml
  tasks:
    # In theory what I require
    - name: Group1 connection
      shell: nc -l -p "{{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ connections }}"
        - port
      poll: 0
      async: 60
      delegate_to: "{{ group1 }}"

Can this be achieved in anyway as well as whats the best way to do this in reality?

"Whats the best way to do this in reality?", such is show in Ansible: How to ping from one Remote Node to another? and How to start netcat listening server in Ansible?. But you would need to adopt the approach and in the first example change and or enhance the Custom Plugin.

Since such connections test are Common Use Cases, I am missing some information in your description. Are you struggling with the data structures and loop only? Since only an example for netcat listener is shown, is it necessary to create and start listener at first? Or do you like to test only if there are already listener running? I do not see where you are going to test the connection between the remote nodes.

I basically need to run a listener on the group I am trying to connect to, then I will run a connect from the current host group to group with listeners on it is the aim. My trouble is with the data structure and loop. I need to basically loop through each dictionary and loop through the dest group (listener group), then each port for each listener host. What is a better way to structure this data?
